# Make new JavaScript variable by combining string & variable

Tags: javascript, string, variables, var

So this is my problem.

```
pageTitle1 = ('This is page one');
pageTitle2 = ('This is page two');
pageTitle3 = ('This is page three');

currentPageTitle = ('pageTitle'+currentPosition);

$("#pageNumber").html(currentPageTitle);
```

I'm trying to display the current page title to the screen based on the currentPosition of the slide I am on. The issue I'm having is the code above is displaying "pageTitle1" to the screen when I need it to display "This is page one". I'm newish to javascript so I have a feeling this an easy fix but days of googling has yielded me nothing.

Comment: or you can simply change currentPageTitle = ('pageTitle'+currentPosition); to currentPageTitle = eval('pageTitle'+currentPosition);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an array instead of naming each variable individually.

```
var pageTitles = [
 'This is page one',
 'This is page two',
 'This is page three'
];

var currentPageTitle = pageTitles[currentPosition];
```

Reason why your code is not working is because it is simply adding the two strings `"pageTitle"` and `currentPosition` and assigning the concatenated string to `currentPageTitle`. What you instead want is to get the value stored in the variable having that name. Assuming you are creating these in the global scope (which is not a good thing btw), you can do:

```
var currentPageTitle = window['pageTitle'+currentPosition];
```

However, going with arrays is a better approach.

Comment: @Mike: if this answer solved your problem, you should mark it as "accepted" by clicking the hollow green checkmark to the left of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this.

```
var pageTitle = new Array();
pageTitle.push('This is page one');
pageTitle.push('This is page two');
pageTitle.push('This is page three');

currentPageTitle = (pageTitle[currentPosition]);
$("#pageNumber").html(currentPageTitle);
```

Or simply use eval (**[really super unrecommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)**)

```
var currentPageTitle = eval('pageTitle'+currentPosition);
```

Comment: too late :) another way of doing it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Without any other modifications, you can replace this line

```
currentPageTitle = ('pageTitle'+currentPosition);
```

with this:

```
currentPageTitle = window['pageTitle'+currentPosition];
```