# for loop help, unknown syntax with javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

say I wanted to use variables like

```
var userpos1 : int;
var userpos2 : int;
var userpos3 : int;

//in a for loop like 

var i=1;
for (i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
    userposi + 1
}
```

how would I place the i so that the for loop goes through all of my variables properly

```
var userpos1var : int;
var userpos2var : int;
var userpos3var : int;

//in a for loop like 

var i=1;
for (i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
    userposivar + 1
}
```

is there something I need to do to this i to make it work properly such as a "" or a [] around it?

Answer (score 3):

Create an array of those vars and go over like this

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    func(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use an array of variables instead, but to do what you are wanting to do, you would write:

```
eval("userpos" + i + "var") + 1
```

eval can be unsafe to use, and does not peform well.

Comment: Recommending the usage of eval() to a user new to javascript warrants a down vote imho.

Comment: Exelian - read my answer. it has not been edited. I recommended and array instead, and warned about it being unsafe and slow. But I'm not going to ignore the fact that eval does _EXACTLY_ what he was asking for this case. As an adult, I assume the user can take the info, the warning, and make a decision.

Comment: I have recommended the use of the Function constructor. Should be better than eval().

Comment: Up-voted because your solution is better than mine; you provided a warning and the proper solution in-respect to the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userpos1 = 1;
var userpos2 = 2;
var userpos3 = 3;
var i = 1;
for (i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
    alert (eval("userpos" + i));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Recommending the usage of eval() to a user new to javascript warrants a down vote imho.

Comment: Your opinion is wrong, I'm simply providing a solution to his question. Would I do it, no, but that's how in JS you can solve the problem he presented.

Comment: Well, you could add a comment about that this is not the preffered way of using eval and warning of it's usage.

Comment: @yetanothercoder - I agree too, but the eval statement itself is not doing anything significant. Maybe you meant something like this: `eval('userpos' + i + ' += ' + i);`

Comment: @stefano: no probs. came across the same the other day :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976090/make-new-javascript-variable-by-combining-string-variable/4976118#4976118 btw you may need to append var to the end.

Comment: @exelian: I dont really appreciate you downvoting Tim below as he has provided a warning

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an array... ?

```
var userpos = new Array(3);

for (var i=0; i<userpos.length; i++) {}
{
    userpos[i] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier done by storing those values in a single array and iterating over the array.

```
someArray = new Array(1, 2, 3);
for (key in someArray)
   alert(someArray[key] );
```

Comment: This function is unsave. If you add functions too the prototype of `Array` it'll break unless you add a check for it.

Comment: for-in is not recommended. It is greedy when it comes to large collections or arrays.

Comment: Both valid points.  My answer was merely to satisfy OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it this way, use an array of user positions:

> //Create an array of 3 positions,
>   setting all to 0
>
> var userPos=new Array(0, 0, 0);
>
> //loop through each position - notice
>   starts at 0.
>
> for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
>
> {
>
> userPos[i] += 1;
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Eval() would do it, but we should not encourage the use of it. Instead, construct an anonymous function.

```
for ( i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
    alert(new Function('return userpos' + i + 'var;')()); // value of userpos1var
}
```

*Update*
JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/madr/AHBrd/

Comment: i don't see how this code is any safer than eval.  either way you're executing source from a string.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Function constructor is a small performance boost (I have no source for that though), plus it's a bit more elegant IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is:

```
var userpos = ['a','b','c'];

for(var i=0; i < userpos.length; i++) {
    userpos[i]; // doing something with it.
}
```